# Javascript Uncaught TypeError: AccountID is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call the AccountID function from the test1 function and store the results in a variable however when i run this i get an uncaught type error that says AccoutID is not a function.

I can only get it to work if i nest the AccoutID function inside of Test1 which is not ideal.

could it be something related to scope?

```
//This script is used to Generate A PDF for the HIN TO HIN email template generator tool 

// This section decalres all variables to be parsed Back 

var username = "";
var password = "";
var SessionID = "";
var IuserID = "";
var AccountID = "";
var AcctDetails = "";

// this function is used to generate a pop up and log you into the platform then capture the session id and user id 

function PlatformLogin() {

    // captures the username and password from the popup form 
    username = $('#username').val();
    password = $('#psw').val();
    // HTTP request to login to the platform using form data
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://autobots.avanteos.com.au/py/Login.py?Username=' + username + '&Password=' + password, false)
    xhr.send()
    // fetches the response from login as JSon then assigns user id and session id variable values 
    var logindetails = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    var SessionID = logindetails["@sSessionId"];
    var IuserID = logindetails["@iUserId"];
    //closes the pop up window 
    document.getElementById("loginPopup").style.display = "none";

}

function AccountDetails(AcctID) {
    // This is a HTTP request to fetch the account details 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://autobots.avanteos.com.au/py/CGiscript.py?SessionId=' + SessionID + '&UserId=' + IuserID + '&AccountID=' + AcctID, false)
    //xhr.open('GET', 'http://autobots.avanteos.com.au/py/CGiscript.py?SessionId=48B18C24724B488B&UserId=1107385&AccountID=3672253', false)
    xhr.send()

    firsttry = xhr.response
    logincheck = firsttry.includes('user not logged in')

    if (logincheck = true) {

        return "Not logged in"

    } else {

        return JSON.parse(firsttry)

    }


}




function test1() {

    // First part of the request fetches the account id for the from account using the from account number 

    var Acctidd = "8308184";

    var FromacctID = AccountID("8308184");



    if (FromAcctID = "Not logged in") {

        PlatformLogin();
        var FromAcctID = AccountID(Acctidd);
    }

    // This part fetches the account id for the TO account using the account number 

    var ToAcctID = AccountID(Acctidd);

    if (ToAcctID = "Not logged in") {

        PlatformLogin();
        var ToAcctID = AccountID(Acctidd);
    }

    // This part fetches the Account details for the From Acccount 

    var FromAcctDetails = AccountDetails(FromAcctID);

    if (FromAcctDetails = "Not logged in") {
        PlatformLogin();
        var FromAcctDetails = AccountDetails(FromAcctID);
    }

    //from data variables are set here 
    var fromacctname = FromAcctDetails["@AccountName"]
    var fromacctnumber = FromAcctDetails["@AccountNumber"]
    var fromacctHIN = FromAcctDetails["@HINType"]
    console.log(fromacctname)
    console.log(fromacctnumber)

    // This part fetches the To Account details 

    var ToAcctDetails = AccountDetails(ToAcctID);

    if (ToAcctDetails = "Not logged in") {
        PlatformLogin();
        var ToAcctDetails = AccountDetails(ToAcctID);
    }

    //To data variables are set here 
    var Toacctname = ToAcctDetails["@AccountName"]
    var Toacctnumber = ToAcctDetails["@AccountNumber"]
    var ToacctHIN = ToAcctDetails["@HINType"]
    console.log(Toacctname)
    console.log(ToacctHIN)




}

function AccountID(AccountNumber) {

    // This HTTP request retrieves the account ID based on an account number 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //xhr.open('GET', 'http://autobots.avanteos.com.au/py/AccountID.py?SessionId=48B18C24724B488B&UserId=1107385&AccountNumber=8308184', false)
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://autobots.avanteos.com.au/py/CGiscript.py?SessionId=' + SessionID + '&UserId=' + IuserID + '&AccountNumber=' + AccountNumber, false)
    xhr.send
    //This code will check if you are logged in 
    Acctidquery = xhr.response
    logincheck = Acctidquery.includes('user not logged in')

    if (logincheck = true) {

        return "Not logged in"

    } else {

        return Acctidquery

    }


}


// This function generates the PDF 

function PDFGENfunc() {


    // First part of the request fetches the account id for the from account using the from account number 

    var FromAcctID = AccountID("8308184");

    if (FromAcctID = "Not logged in") {

        PlatformLogin();
        var FromAcctID = AccountID("8308184");
    }

    // This part fetches the account id for the TO account using the account number 

    var ToAcctID = AccountID("8308184");

    if (ToAcctID = "Not logged in") {

        PlatformLogin();
        var ToAcctID = AccountID("8308184");
    }

    // This part fetches the Account details for the From Acccount 

    var FromAcctDetails = AccountDetails(FromAcctID);

    if (FromAcctDetails = "Not logged in") {
        PlatformLogin();
        var FromAcctDetails = AccountDetails(FromAcctID);
    }

    //from data variables are set here 
    var fromacctname = FromAcctDetails["@AccountName"]
    var fromacctnumber = FromAcctDetails["@AccountNumber"]
    var fromacctHIN = FromAcctDetails["@HINType"]

    // This part fetches the To Account details 

    var ToAcctDetails = AccountDetails(ToAcctID);

    if (ToAcctDetails = "Not logged in") {
        PlatformLogin();
        var ToAcctDetails = AccountDetails(ToAcctID);
    }

    //To data variables are set here 
    var fromacctname = ToAcctDetails["@AccountName"]
    var fromacctnumber = ToAcctDetails["@AccountNumber"]
    var fromacctHIN = ToAcctDetails["@HINType"]





    // initialises jsPDF

    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4')

    // holds the text content 

    var reportTitle = "Colonial First State Custom Solutions Level 1 105 Camberwell Road Hawthorn East VIC 3123 PO Box 1012 Camberwell VIC 3124 Telephone (03)9805111     Facsimile (03)98134182 "

    // this variable allows me to wrap report tittle to 90

    var splitTitle = doc.splitTextToSize(reportTitle, 90);

    // this is the image data for the cfs logo in URI data form 

    var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4RD4RXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABAE7AAIAAAAPAAAISodpAAQAAAABAAAIWpydAAEAAAAeAAAQ0uocAAcAAAgMAAAAPgAAAAAc6gAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFNob2tvLCBUaW5hc2hlAAAABZADAAIAAAAUAAAQqJAEAAIAAAAUAAAQvJKRAAIAAAADNzMAAJKSAAIAAAADNzMAAOocAAcAAAgMAAAInAAAAAAc6gAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADIwMjA6MDI6MDQgMTE6MTc6MjUAMjAyMDowMjowNCAxMToxNzoyNQAAAFMAaABvAGsAbwAsACAAVABpAG4AYQBzAGgAZQAAAP/hCyFodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0n77u/JyBpZD0nVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkJz8+DQo8eDp4bXBtZXRhIHhtbG5zOng9ImFkb2JlOm5zOm1ldGEvIj48cmRmOlJERiB4bWxuczpyZGY9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkvMDIvMjItcmRmLXN5bnRheC1ucyMiPjxyZGY6RGVzY3JpcHRpb24gcmRmOmFib3V0PSJ1dWlkOmZhZjViZGQ1LWJhM2QtMTFkYS1hZDMxLWQzM2Q3NTE4MmYxYiIgeG1sbnM6ZGM9Imh0dHA6Ly9wdXJsLm9yZy9kYy9lbGVtZW50cy8xLjEvIi8+PHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9InV1aWQ6ZmFmNWJkZDUtYmEzZC0xMWRhLWFkMzEtZDMzZDc1MTgyZjFiIiB4bWxuczp4bXA9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC8iPjx4bXA6Q3JlYXRlRGF0ZT4yMDIwLTAyLTA0VDExOjE3OjI1LjcyNTwveG1wOkNyZWF0ZURhdGU+PC9yZGY6RGVzY3JpcHRpb24+PHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9InV1aWQ6ZmFmNWJkZDUtYmEzZC0xMWRhLWFkMzEtZDMzZDc1MTgyZjFiIiB4bWxuczpkYz0iaHR0cDovL3B1cmwub3JnL2RjL2VsZW1lbnRzLzEuMS8iPjxkYzpjcmVhdG9yPjxyZGY6U2VxIHhtbG5zOnJkZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS8wMi8yMi1yZGYtc3ludGF4LW5zIyI+PHJkZjpsaT5TaG9rbywgVGluYXNoZTwvcmRmOmxpPjwvcmRmOlNlcT4NCgkJCTwvZGM6Y3JlYXRvcj48L3JkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbj48L3JkZjpSREY+PC94OnhtcG1ldGE+DQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDw/eHBhY2tldCBlbmQ9J3cnPz7/2wBDAAcFBQYFBAcGBQYIBwcIChELCgkJChUPEAwRGBUaGRgVGBcbHichGx0lHRcYIi4iJSgpKywrGiAvMy8qMicqKyr/2wBDAQcICAoJChQLCxQqHBgcKioqKioqKioqKioqKioqKioqKioqKioqKioqKioqKioqKioqKioqKioqKioqKioqKir/wAARCAA2AH0DASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDLtJtUvbiO2tJ7yeeQ7UjjlYlj+dbF9o+oaQ4i1rX0s7jGTbi4klkX/eC5A/Ouq+EdrFbaVrmtlFe4toykZI+6AhY/nx+VeaTTyXU8lxcOXlmYu7k8sTyTXz8o8kFJ6tn6rTqPEYmdGCUYwtd2V2369DoLbSNR1G2uJtI11bw20ZllhE8kcgQckhW6/hWGNQvSP+P25/7/ADf40thfz6Zd/abVgsmx4zkZBVlKkH8DXSSeHrHQPB9lrGsxPd3eon/RbQOUREAzucjk8Y4HqKlLnV1pbc2k1hpctVKXM0o6K99b9l8zmvt97/z+3P8A3+b/ABrct9G1W68MXeuW+sb7ezwJoxPJvBOOPTvVjw1pukeLL5tJe2/s29kRmtp4ZGZGYDO1lYnt3BrX0i2lsfhP4vtbldssF0I3X0IKg1dOm3q3dWf4HLi8XGDUIx5ZKUbppbN2OE+33v8Az+3P/f5v8aPt97/z+3P/AH+b/Gun1jQNP8JaPYHU4Gv9Vv4/O8ppCkUCe+OWP4+tHh/Q9O8Y295aWUH9natbxGaEJIXinA6qQ3IPI5z3qPZz5uW+vY6frmH9n7bk9z+aytva/e3yOY+33v8Az+3P/f5v8aX7fe/8/tz/AN/m/wAa63/hHtDh+HEPiK7huxcm4MBgSYbXYEjBJHA4yaTQNI0XxP4e1nbYGwv9Pg8+OWKZmVxg8EN9P1p+yndK+rVyHjsMoufs3yxfK3ZaO9u/5GX4d0nVfEkl0lrq4tzbR+Y32i6Zd3059qx/t97k/wCm3P8A3+b/ABrqPAWg6T4ka+t9QtpfMtrVp1lScjcc9NuKxdC/skR3TalaXF9dbALS1hyFdu5cjnA9BRytxi+9xqtBVqsXG/LbSy6+d/ztYofb73/n9uf+/wA3+NbfhvR9V8T3bWtjq/lTqhcpNPICVGMnjjvW9oPhi18RaXqi32gSaRcWtuZre4j8xVc8/KQ+c9Kh+EBz4zkPrYyfzWqhSfPFS2Zz4jGU3h60qUbShbonv6XRD8NLq6f4i2EU11PIuJQVaViDhG7E175Xz98M/wDkpll9Zv8A0Bq+ga9LBfw36nyfEiSxcbL7K/U8B+HPiy18PXl1ZatkadqChZHAz5bYIyfYg4NUNT8E6lbXb/2TGNUsWOYLi1cOGXtkA5BrOCeEdo/4q9f/AAXS05R4TT7njHb/ALunyiub6riHFRlB6bHu/wBq5dCvKvRrpOVrpptO3XpqW4/CVzDBJca7cQ6VAiEhZnBlkOOFVBzz6mt/WJl8YeA9G/s1lfUdJTyrizDAOVwBuUfxD5R09a5Qp4SJyfF4J9Tp8tATwkDkeLwCOhGnS0LC4iKaVN2Yqma4CpKNSWIXNF3Xuu3Zq2+vqdF4E099G8QJruu50+xsUdt0/wArSMVICqvUnmtq0kudU+Hvi+7Fs6SaheefBER8zKSpGB34rhGHhNzl/GO4+rafKaP+KUHTxkeP+nCWrhh8RBcqpu2v4nPiMfl1ep7WWIXN7vR2tF3t83udZ41f/hMrDS9Z0b/SJYLf7PeWqH97CwOc7epGc8j2pngNf+ESnvPEOvf6JFHbtFbwyHEk7kg4VeuOOvvXLBfCStuXxhtb1Gnyg0MPCbtl/GG4+rafKTS+rYnn9p7N3K/tDLfq31T6wuT0d7Xva/62Oy1GK5m+CNvvhYTHUGndMcqpZzux6c9ah+GkEv8AZfiV/LbZNp5jjbHDthuB6muTx4U/6HH/AMkJaMeEx08Y4+mny0/q+I51L2b0ViHjsu+rzoLEL3pc2z01Tt+B1/wntZ4b3V5JoXjRrBo1ZxgFt33frR4C8y28N+I7KyAt/ERjBt1fCyFcdFz36/mK5DHhP/ocf/JCWjHhPcG/4THkd/7PlzRHD4iKilTel/xHWx2XVpVJPEL3+Xo/s9+6fU7/AOHtvqds+sR63culxdWbJBa3NxmVzzkhSeOorM+FFldWXjK4+2QPAI7R43MgwFbK/Kff2rk8eE927/hMfm67v7Plz+dGPCf/AEOJ55P+gS01h8QnH929CZ47L5RrL6wv3iX2Xpbsb/w5gltvijZxXEbRyAzZVxgj5Gr32vC/hwvh4+PrA6d4k+3XW2TbB9jkTcNhz8x44HNe6104alOlBxmraniZ1i6OKxEZ0ZcyUUr+ep8PL90UtIv3RS19IfHBXc6DYafcfC3WtXl0a1udQ0+6hhhkZXO5XIzuAbk81w1d/wCHLuO0+FGvWUerWtrqN7dQy28X2oJIUXG7vx34NZVNi4blHS4I9Rl0mB/DFlFd3N+DbmR3hivIxw0TZJ/iK4I96rN4R1LXPFWt2elWlnaz2MkryWKXHEaoeQhP3gOmaXwzrd3deL/DzazqINrpl4solupv9Wm8FvmPXpnFdPo99p9v8SfF2oTapYpaX1teJbSm4XEjSnKAfX9KhuUW7FpKSOObwbqAge4F1pz2sUAnnuY7tXjgUttAcjOGJ4AGav8Ah/wDPrHiC2sZ9Rskgmtmu1mhm3+ZEA2Sox1BXBBxim+Dr690O31MafqGmrcny45dPvijW97HznBPykqcdxwTXWaPq3hez+IGk3cLWOlSXGlzxagtvKWtYJ3GFCtyBnvjgZFEpSV0EYxdrnmLWiRahFbzXdu8bMgeeB96KpPJz7Cu+8S6AnhPxEhbwpFfeFwU23ihpWniIG5/NU/K3U44HSuFFhDZazb2upXMMluJUE8tpKJAE3fMQw4zjJrt/C19qPhHxVEtt4os38OLNmZmuw8UsHf9197eR2Azmqm3umKFupif8Iakngp/EianaRQyX32e3jklwAm0sQxx9/7ox9aq2ngzUb26tLOK509b68jEtvZvdASuCMgdMAkDoTmun1S/0jXvhxqNjot1Z2Dp4glvobO5lEREDKQpXPXr0HStHTNT0XS/Ffhq90e90Wx0KGGJrpmVTcGbBDh8gvnOORgAVHPJJlcsbnH2vgp5vB17rdzqFpbNb3aWoillxtc53hzjgjAwKqxeD9RZrFLiaysptRAazgurjY8yk4VgMcAnoWxmuouWtLzwP4o0WPVNPS9fXPt0QkuVCSxHurdD16dau+KtaHiC503V/DeraLEqWkUU8N6IkltpE7jepLL3BXPTpTU5XFyRsZ3wlsbnTfjRZWV/C0Fzbi4jljbqrCJuK+nq+a/htfy6n8eLa8uL46hJIJt10Y9nm4hIzt7Djj2r6TrlxHxr0Omh8Oh5mPgH4NA66l/4Ff8A1qP+FCeDfXUv/Ar/AOtRRWXtZ9zT2cOwf8KE8G+upf8AgV/9aj/hQfg311L/AMCv/rUUUe1n3F7OHYP+FCeDfXUv/Ar/AOtR/wAKD8G+upf+BX/1qKKPaz7h7OHYP+FCeDfXUv8AwK/+tR/woTwb66l/4Ff/AFqKKPa1O4ezh2D/AIUJ4N9dS/8AAr/61H/Cg/BvrqX/AIFf/Wooo9rPuHs4dg/4UH4NPfUv/Ar/AOtR/wAKD8G+upf+BX/1qKKPaz7h7OHYP+FB+DfXUv8AwK/+tR/woPwb66l/4Ff/AFqKKPaz7h7OHY1fDfwk8NeFteg1fSze/aoAwTzZ9y/MpU5GPQ13FFFQ5OWrLUVHRH//2Q=='

    // set the font size here 
    doc.setFontSize(9);
    doc.setFont('Calibri');

    // actually displays split title 

    doc.text(150, 20, splitTitle)

    //displays the image 
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 20, 30, 12);

    // initial text

    var inittext = '<p>[Date]</p>\
    <p>&nbsp;</p>\
    <p><strong>Custom solutions Stock Transfer:</strong></p>\
    <p>Dear Core,</p>\
    <p>Please Accept our authority for the transfer of the below listed securities to perform and internal transfer.</p>'

    doc.fromHTML(inittext, 15, 40)

    //displays the date

    doc.autoTable({
        startY: 80,
        head: [
            [{ content: 'From Account', colSpan: 1, rowSpan: 1, styles: { halign: 'center', fillColor: [107, 107, 107] } }],
        ],
    })

    doc.autoTable({
        startY: 90,
        head: [['Acct Name', 'Acct #', 'HIN', 'Sponsor A/C']],
        body: [

            ['John smith', '123456', '123456', '123456', '123456']

        ],
    })

    doc.autoTable({
        startY: 110,
        head: [
            [{ content: 'To Account', colSpan: 1, rowSpan: 1, styles: { halign: 'center', fillColor: [107, 107, 107] } }],
        ],
    })


    doc.autoTable({
        startY: 120,
        head: [['Acct Name', 'Acct #', 'HIN', 'Sponsor A/C']],
        body: [

            ['John smith', '123456', '123456', '123456', '123456']

        ],
    })

    doc.autoTable({
        startY: 140,
        head: [
            [{ content: 'To Account', colSpan: 1, rowSpan: 1, styles: { halign: 'center', fillColor: [107, 107, 107] } }],
        ],
    })

    doc.autoTable({
        startY: 150,
        styles: { theme: 'striped' },
        head: [['Stock', 'QTY']],
        body: [

            ['John smith', '123456']

        ],
    })






    // saves the document 
    doc.save("Cows1.pdf");




}
```

Comment: Your error is not reproducible given the code you have shared. When i copy + paste your code into the console the `AccountID` function runs fine when calling `test1()` and it errors out inside of `AccountID` saying `SessionID` is not defined, which is to be expected, since `SessionID` is not defined.

Comment: would sharing the entirety of the code help ? , could it be something outside of the 2 functions affecting this?

Comment: for me, it would helpful if you share enough of the code such that when you copy+paste whatever you have shared into the console, it errors out at the same error your question is asking about

Comment: Question has been udpated with complete code , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - My issue was that at the beginning of my code i set the name of my function as a variable equals to blank , i should not have declared it as a variable.